# Read to the end of file in java

Tags: java, java-io

I do read serial interface file in Linux via Java. Sometimes I just need to discard all data and read only what is new.

Explanation: There is loads of data and new is coming so I do have to discard existing buffer and start to wait for new data. External board just keeps sending. And I end up reading old data, just in few iterations I have current value. I need just skip to end and wait for new data set only instead reading all old crap.

```
String file = "/dev/ttyO1";
FileInputStream inputStream  = new FileInputStream(file);

private static byte[] readUntil(InputStream in, int timeout) throws IOException {
//        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (true) {
        if (in.available() > 0) {
            if (in.read() == 83)
                break;
        }
        try { Thread.sleep(20); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    byte[] text = new byte[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        text[i] = (byte) in.read();
        if (text[i]=="E".getBytes()[0]) break;
        try { Thread.sleep(20); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    in.read(); // just read last one
    return text;
}
```

I just cannot figure out how to discard the existing data and read only new coming.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? I don't understand.

Comment: what is the purpose of `Thread.sleep(20)`??

Comment: Thread.sleep(20) - I was intended to save processor power... I might be wrong...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just read all the data, as fast as possible. When data isn't available, the read will block. The available/sleep loop is therefore pointless. I don't understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what a 'serial interface file in Linux' is. But I assume it is a simple file which has some text appended all the time and you want to wait for the new stuff appended and not read the whole file from scratch. You could use the `RandomAccessFile` class' `seek(long)` method to skip data. Or you could just sleep for some time when you reached the end of file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/file.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 50) { // read only 50 bytes
        byte b = (byte)fis.read();

        if (b == -1) { // end of file, wait
            Thread.sleep(500L);
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print((char) b);
        i++;
    }
    fis.close();
}
```

This is just a simple example. I read only up to 50 bytes, but you want to read much more than that. Maybe you could use a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that what you really want is to flush all data in the incoming  buffers of the serial port.

On Linux, in a C program, [you would be able to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018281/unix-how-to-clear-the-serial-port-i-o-buffer):

```
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH)
```

To flush the incoming buffer. But you won't be able to do this directly from Java - it's not a platform-independent functionality.

You could write a small C program that performs this operation and then pipes the data from `/dev/ttyO1` to stdout. You can start that program from your Java code using `ProcessBuilder` and read its data instead of reading the serial port directly.

---

Thinking about it a bit more, you don't need the C program to do any piping, you just need to invoke it once and after that you can open `/dev/tty01` from Java.

Here's a small C program that will do this:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        int fd = open(argv[i], O_NOCTTY, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd >= 0) {
            int result = tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
            close(fd);
            if (result == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Couldn't open file %s; %s\n",
                        argv[0], argv[i], strerror(errno));
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Couldn't open file %s; %s\n",
                    argv[0], argv[i], strerror(errno));
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile with `gcc -o tcflush tcflush.c` and run with `tcflush /dev/tty01`.

Comment: I think it's possible not just with external program, but with JNI, it's still will be platform dependent, but without extra process.

Comment: @AlexanderKudrevatykh true. If performance is of high importance, the OP should look to JNI. But better check first using an external program if this does what he requires (there may be timing issues between flushing the buffer and reading the data for example)

Answer (score 0):

> External board just keeps sending.

This looks more like a target for an event-driven approach than the usual sequential-read.

Have you considered using [RXTX](https://github.com/rxtx/rxtx) or the [jSSC](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/)?
You can find an example in the Arduino IDE source code: [SerialMonitor](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/app/src/processing/app/SerialMonitor.java) and [Serial](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/app/src/processing/app/Serial.java).

Answer (score -1):

Your aim is very unclear from the code. I presume you want some functionality like tail command in linux..if so, Below code is helpful..please run it and check it out..

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileCheck {

    static long sleepTime = 1000 * 1;
    static String file_path = "/dev/ttyO1";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_path));
            String currentLine = null;
            while (true) {
                if ((currentLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(currentLine);
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
            }
            input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It reads file and when you add contains, It displays new constants on console. Now, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: The readLine() method returns null at end of stream. At this point, the peer has closed the connection, so there will never be any more data. It is therefore pointless to sleep and try the readLine() again. -1

Comment: Dear, Pls run the program to have importance of  sleep..it will chk file for data after  an internal..

Comment: Can you tell me what problem could be occurred with above code. Just for my information.

Comment: The importance of the sleep is zero, whether 'dear' or otherwise.