# Mac OSX: How to clear the serial port I/O buffer

Tags: c, macos, io, serial-port, flush

I'm writing an application in C that uses the serial port for communication with a Bluetooth device. I've found I can close the com port, power cycle the Bluetooth device, and reopen the port to find stale data sitting in the read buffer from a previous connection. I need to flush the I/O buffer. The solution would seem to be to use

```
tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH)
```

which, according to OS X's man page for tcflush, should

> Flush both data received but not read and data written but not transmitted.

However, that seems to be ineffective.

According to [Unix: How to clear the serial port I/O buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018281/unix-how-to-clear-the-serial-port-i-o-buffer/) the solution on Unix is to use

```
ioctl(fd, TCFLUSH, 2)
```

But `TCFLUSH` isn't defined on Mac and I'm not sure what the equivalent is.

Comment: Would reading and discarding the remaining data work?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Possibly, but how would I distinguish between old data that should be discarded and new data that shouldn't? Surely there must be a way to open a port and immediately flush the i/o buffer. Flushing it on close might also help.

Comment: Are you sure the old data is actually being buffered by the computer, and not the Bluetooth device?

Comment: @duskwuff Yes, I'm sure. I have additional diagnostics I can connect to the Bluetooth device to see what it is sending.